# Servlet's service and init method are being called, but not doGet while I am extending ZuulServlet

Tags: java, servlets, netflix-zuul

Before I start, I would say, I have already seen similar question  [Servlet's service and init method are being called, but not doGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608493/servlets-service-and-init-method-are-being-called-but-not-doget)
but that dint help me much.
Point to be noted here is that my servlet class extending *com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet* (which does routing for specific reason) and in service method I am calling  *super.service(servletRequest,servletResponse);*.When I do http get call, I see my service() method is called but doGet() method is not called however in response I get a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" without any body which is of course my doGet() method not sending. Below is my code snippet.

```
public class AppHealthServlet extends ZuulServlet {
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    logger.info("AppHealthServlet called ");
    message = "pong";
}

@Override
public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                    ServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("AppHealthServlet service called ");
    try {
        RequestContext.getCurrentContext().set("health", true);
        super.service(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    } finally {
        logger.info("AppHealthServlet service done ");
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doGet(req, resp);
    logger.info("AppHealthServlet doGet called ");
    // Set response content type
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
    resp.setStatus(AppHealthServlet.SC_OK);
}
}
```

Would be appreciated if anyone can help me to figure it out where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ZuulServlet` isn't meant to be used like this. If you look at the source code of what [`ZuulServlet.service`](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/1.x/zuul-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/zuul/http/ZuulServlet.java#L64) does, it basically hands everything off to a `ZuulRunner`.

It seems to me that you need to be looking into hooking into the Zuul routing, rather than trying to extend `ZuulServlet` yourself.

Comment: I ended up writing a new servlet which extends HttpServlet instead of ZuulServlet and it does the work for me